# android 7.0 , picture in weex will show square ,even I set the picture show circle

Tags: android, weex

only in 7.0 or high ,picture will show square ,I hope someone can tell me how to deal with it question.

```
            <div class="avatar_border">
                <image class="avatar" :src="avatarUrl" placeholder="default.png"></image>
            </div>
```

// this is style

```
.avatar_border {
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 100px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 100px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
    border-top-left-radius:100px;
    border-top-right-radius: 100px;
}
```

Comment: set this property value in your css class `border-radius: 50%;`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think this is ok

```
border-radius: 100;
```

may be the problem is inside your android code,

```
IWXImgLoaderAdapter
```

you should know you need to implements **IWXImgLoaderAdapter** and Override a method named setImage.

So I just suggested you do something like this

```
@Override
public void setImage(final String url, final ImageView view,
                     WXImageQuality quality, final WXImageStrategy strategy) {
    LogUtil.v("准备加载图片URL---" + url);
    Picasso.with(WXEnvironment.getApplication())
            .load(url)
            .into(view);
}
```

because when I ues the Glide, use the Css-style set circle image is not working...
by the way, my phone is nexues 5x 7.1.2